# Even and odd functions

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Given $f(x)= \sqrt{1-\cos x}$.

Period $0<x<2 \pi$

Is it a even function or a odd function?

Whether the $f(x)$ has to be converted to square root of $2$ multiplied by $\sin(x/2)$.

Comment: You might want to read this to learn how to format your posts http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: [Welcome to math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour)! Please try to make your post clearer and also tell us what you already understand. You may [edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1063015/edit) your post by clicking the edit button. Be sure to check out the [help center](http://math.stackexchange.com/help) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing the fact that $y=\cos x$ is even,

$f(-x)=\sqrt{1-\cos(-x)}=\sqrt{1-\cos x}=f(x)$, and therefore $f(x)$ is even.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=\sqrt2\left|\sin\dfrac x2\right|$

$\left|\sin\dfrac x2\right|=\sin\dfrac x2$ if $\sin\dfrac x2\ge0$

Else $\left|\sin\dfrac x2\right|=-\sin\dfrac x2$

But $\sin(-ax)=-\sin(ax)$